# Override Zend Framework locale XML file

Tags: zend-framework, locale

I'm trying to override the XML file used in translation. The goal is to change the grouping symbol of the formatted numbers :

```
Zend_Locale_Format::toInteger($value)
```

This code generates a string, with a non breakable space character in it for the grouping symbol. I need it to be a simple space character.

I found out that the character used is defined in a XML file, in Zend/Locale/Data/xx.xml. I looked for a way to override this file, but I found nothing except people telling me to change the value directly in the XML file...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks